# Prolems in installation Sigma Photo Pro with Wine

Tags: wine

I installed Sigma Photo Pro (a windows program) through Wine, but after the installation completed, the program wouldn't start. So I try to remove the program in order to reinstall it again.

But I am not able to remove the program, so I tried typing "wine /home/paul/Downloads/SPP_5.5.3_setup.exe" in the terminal. After some steps it says "msiexec.exe has encountered a problem and needs to be closed", I checked detail error info, it says "wine unhandled exception assertion failed in 32-bit".

Should I try older version of Sigma Photo Pro setup files, e.g. SPP 5.0.0 instead of 5.5.3?
And is there a way to remove the program? Will it be harmful leaving the installed SPP_5.5.3 in Ubuntu?

Comment: PS: should I try to download a 32bit SPP_5.5.3_setup.exe file to install?

Comment: Cannot test this but it appears that [RawTherapy](http://rawtherapee.com/) included Foveon support in release >= 4.0. It will run natively on Ubuntu so it may be worth a try. Gimp also claims to support Foveon with the `ufraw` plugin.

Comment: Thanks Takkat. It is great to see more softwares are there for Ubuntu. But is this case  I saw report of RawTherapy on Foveon files, I am not satisfied with its result.

Comment: According to the [Wine AppDB](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=23705&iTestingId=84066) 32-bit versions up to 5.x of Sigma Photo Pro are rated `Platinum` (i.e. fully supported) in Ubuntu 14.04. Version 6.x will not run.

Comment: Thanks Takkat for info. I tried 32-bit version of Sigma Photo Pro version 5.3.1, but failed, same error: Unhandled exception: assertion failed in 32-bit code (0xf7712ba0).

Can anybody give me a hand where did I go wrong? Thanks a lot.

Comment: In the Wine AppDB people said: "Need to enable multilibs and install some extra 32bit libraries `lib32-lcms2 lib32-mpg123 lib32-ncurses`" - no idea if that will help however.

Comment: Thanks Takkat. That was solved. It strangely generate a error info, but the installation has successfully finished. It just needs a restart. After the restart, it works like a charm. Strange, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can prove that wine does the job nicely. Both SPP 5.3 and 4.0 with wine are successfully installed on Ubuntu 15.10, though SPP 5.3 runs a little slowly but it works. I then picked an older version (SPP 4.0) to install and runs like a charm. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I use SPP 5.5 with Wine 1.7 installed from wine ppa and it works flawlessly. Just right click on exe and install, wine takes care of getting essential files to make it run. Use x64 version of SPP 5x. 6x sadly doesn't run even with experimental WINE.